# What is the importance of prototype in this example?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I found this example in w3school related to topic "Prototype" in js. My question is that we can do the same with creating simple function then what is the importance of prototype. Can anyone explain.Thanx in advance.

```
<button type="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me</button>
```

## JS

```
function doSomething(){
    var fruits=["apple","banana","papaya"]
    console.log(fruits)
    fruits.uCase()
    console.log(fruits)
}

Array.prototype.uCase=function(){
  for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        this[i]=this[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mutating built-in prototypes is a very bad idea (and you might consider looking at something more reputable than w3schools)

Comment: So am i creating a new feature in Javascript Array. Please clear my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not alter built in prototype which you are  doing in this case for Array(build in Array of JS).

Now whats use of prototype :  Let's say you want to define common method for all objects(instances) to Function. Then its been used.

Example : In memory wise its shared to all instances of function constructor

```js
function person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

person.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log("hello   " + this.name);
}

var obj1 = new person("vips");
var obj2 = new person("bips");

obj1.printName();
obj2.printName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototypes allows you to easily define methods to all instances of a particular object. The beauty is that the method is applied to the prototype, so it is only stored in the memory once, but every instance of the object has access to it.It is pretty fast.